# Lock folder using c# and want access files from this folder

Tags: c#

Can we do lock on folder and we have to access folder's file using c#. Is this possible?

Comment: _Is this possible?_ Have you tried it first?

Comment: @SonerGönül I tried already i cannot access then i am tell it is possible

Answer (score 4):

using C# you can lock a folder by using DirectorySecurity Class To Lock a folder use:

```
string folderPath = "@D:\myFolderName";
  string adminUserName = Environment.UserName;// getting your adminUserName
  DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(folderPath);
  FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(adminUserName,         
  FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny)
  dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(fsa);
  Directory.SetAccessControl(folderPath, dirSecurity);
```

This Code will Lock the folder for given the given user
To Unlock the folder use the same DirectorySecurityClass but instead of dirSecurity.AddAccessControl use RemoveAccessControl Method  :

```
ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);
```

Hope that this will solve your problem

Comment: I can change folder permission and we can direct access folder

Answer (score -1):

[How to lock a folder](http://www.bitsbyta.com/2011/01/lock-and-unlock-folder-cnet.html). Read here.

And how [access files](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/) from a directory, here.

EDIT - [Lock folder with password](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con) . Then you can access files from  it with using the password you made for it.

And please do a research on Web before asking. It is easy:)

Comment: I want lock folder using password and then access folder